# Racket: argument is non-null error

Tags: eval, racket, quote

At first I defined `HALF`, `QUARTER` and `EIGHT` to their values with `define` and with it the quoted symbols would get introduced as arguments in the `note` function thus making an error. Then I used `let` and now I get the error

```
stream-rec->C: argument is not non-null `stream-rec' pointer
  argument: #f
```

My theory is that stream still processes `HALF` as `'HALF` instead of `30000`. I tried putting it into an `eval` list in `note` , in `random-length` in `let` bindings and in `random-note` and neither worked. What can I do?

```
#lang racket

(require rsound
     rsound/piano-tones)

;Where notes are made.
(define stream (make-pstream))
(define count 10000)
(define (note y x)
  (pstream-queue stream (clip (piano-tone y) 0 20000) count)
  (set! count (+ count x)))

;Defining length of notes.
(let ([HALF 30000]) 30000)
(let ([QUARTER 15000]) 15000)
(let ([EIGHT 7500]) 7500)

(define (random-element list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))

;Getting a random note length. 
(define (random-length)
  (random-element '(HALF QUARTER QUARTER EIGHT)))

;Getting a random note and note length.
(define (random-note)
  (note (random-element '(40 42 43 45 47 48 50 52 54 55 57 59 60 62 64))   (random-length)))


;Main loop for creating the notes.
(for ([i (in-range 32)])
  (random-note))


;For the program not to close itself before runing loop, only after pstream-  queue is emptied.
(define ok-to-exit? #f)
(pstream-queue-callback stream (lambda () (set! ok-to-exit? #t)) count)

(let loop ()
  (sleep 0.1)
  (unless ok-to-exit?
    (loop)))
```

Comment: You want `(list HALF QUARTER QUARTER EIGHT)`, not `'(HALF QUARTER QUARTER EIGHT)`. The latter produces a list of symbols because quoting completely disables any evaluation (it is not a shorthand for `list`).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `(define HALF 30000)` instead of `(let ([HALF 30000]) 30000)`. Let creates a definition that's only available within the body of the let, but define creates a definition that's available anywhere in that scope (in this case anywhere in the module).

Comment: I already changed that. Now it works perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between quote and list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Comment: My question was first even if it's less general.

Comment: @TheodorBerza [On the SE network, it is perfectly okay for older questions to be closed as duplicates of newer ones](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/465378), and [the idea of canonical duplicates is common and useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/canonical/info).